# Change row height of particular telerik mvc grid

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

I am working on ASP.net MVC using c# project.

I am using Telerik MVC grid for my work.

I want to reduce row height of grid.

Any type of technology is ok like jquery, css or itself in telerik grid

Can some one help me?

Comment: u can do that with simply adding class to that particular telerik row and then with css set its height

Comment: I tried it like, my grid is GridView1..#GridView1 tbody tr{height:30px;}..bt its not working

Comment: try like below methods...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try use the grid method itself to get this is all the documentation gives,

```
$("#GridView1").kendoGrid({
                columns: [
                    {    title:"col1",
 field: "COL1",
 width: 100 }, 
height:200]
});
```

I found that the best way is to do it in css:

```
.k-grid tbody tr{height:38px;}
```

Or you can try something like below too

```
 div#MyGrid .t-grid-content {
    height: 100px !important;
}
```

hope this helps...

Comment: Thnx for reply...but I want to set row height below 10 px..it is not allowing me for that..below 10 it is not reflecting any change

Comment: try Scrollable method .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Height(10))